# How to simplify using boolean algebra?

Tags: boolean-algebra

I have the following problem in my assignment:

"Verify, using Boolean algebra, the following equality:

NOT((A AND NOT B) OR (NOT A AND B)) == ((A AND B) OR (NOT A AND NOT B)). "

I am able to do it with Karnaugh Maps and Truth tables, but I'm stuck on the formal procedure using Boolean Algebra.

Thanks in advance for your kind help!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be directly about programming: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374816/boolean-logic-questions-are-general-computer-questions

Comment: Do you know de Morgan's laws?  You'll need it here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about boolean algebra / mathematics instead of directly about programming / coding / programming tools / software algorithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out on my own:

**Steps:**

1. ~((A AND ~B) AND (~A AND B))    .... Original Eqn.
2. ((~A OR ~~B) AND (~~A OR ~B))   .... DeMorgan's Law
3. ((~A OR B ) AND (A OR ~B)       .... Elimination of double negation

*Introducing mathematical symbols as it makes it a bit clearer in my opinion*

4. (~A (~B + A) * B (~B + A)       .... "Factor out" (~A * B) and carry out multiplication
5. (~A*~B)+(~A*A)+(B*~B)+(B*A)     .... "Multiply out the terms"
6. (~A*~B) + 1 + 1 + (B*A)         .... Excluded middle
7. (~A*~B) + (A*B)                 .... Required Answer

Answer (score 3):

Using DeMorgan's laws (http://www.ask-math.com/de-morgans-law.html) we can simplify down the left side:

1. !((**A** *and* !**B**) *or* (!**A** *and* **B**))
2. !(**A** *and* !**B**) *and* !(!**A** *and* **B**)
3. (!**A** *or* **B**) *and* (**A** *or* !**B**)

Next we use the Product of Sums to get:

(!**A** *and* **A**) *or* (**B** *and* **A**) *or* (!**A** *and* !**B**) *or* (**B** *and* !**B**)

Since (!**A** *and* **A**) is false and (**B** *and* !**B**) is false we reduce to:

(**B** *and* **A**) *or* (!**A** *and* !**B**).

This matches the right side of the equation.